# How to call the system imagePicker method for avatar

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to do a function of showing an imagePicker which like choose a picture for the avatar in the contacts, please see screenshot below:

[image: the UI for take picture for avator]

And I have found any methods in UIImagePicker class to call, the UIImagePicker just show UI for take a normal picture not for avatar.

So, is that mean, i must do it by myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can display let the user edit the image after taking an Image with the UIImagePickerController by setting the allowsEditing property to YES.